# Requesting facebook permission not working

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I have a small facebook script which should get the user_about_me, publish_actions, publish_stream permissions. I set these permissions in my app

[image]

My code looks like that:

```
<?php
  require_once("src/facebook.php");

  $config = array();
  $config['appId'] = 'xxx';
  $config['secret'] = 'xxx';

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);


//2. retrieving user
$user = $facebook->getUser();

//3. requesting 'me' to API
$me = null;
if ($user) {
  try {
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
  }
}

//4. login or logout
if ($me) {
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}


?>
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>php-sdk</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php if ($me): ?>
    <?php echo "Welcome, ".$me['first_name']. ".<br />"; ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">
      Logout
    </a>
    <?php else: ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">
        Login
      </a>
    <?php endif ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

But when I login via facebook, it only requests the basic info and not the publish permissions.

[image]
Whats wrong?

Comment: *Sigh* You have not read the description of the settings you made. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/

Comment: You're right. I added the `$params = array(
  'scope' => 'user_about_me, publish_actions, publish_stream',
  'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost/test.php'
);`

But when I now want to post a comment on a status like that `$facebook->api('/475464812509231/comments','post',array('message' => 'test'));` I receive the error `Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) Permissions error thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\src\base_facebook.php on line 1254`

Comment: Have you gone through the login flow again after this? If you connected to the app before, then you have to remove it from your user settings first - otherwise this script will recognize a user, and not go through login again, and therefor you can not grant the new permissions the app is asking for ...

Comment: Yeah I removed it and logged in again. It now request for the right permissions.
The crazy thing is: `$facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array('message'=> 'test'));` is working but commenting on a post like `$facebook->api('/475464812509231/comments','post',array('message' => 'test'));` not.